# How to set small image as default to product after import many products from CSV? - magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8, product, import, image

I just import many products form CSV (about 9 000). On back-end i see imported product images but they aren't set as base, small and thumbnail image - default set is "no image"

Do you know how can I change it for all of my products? "Fixes" for Magento 1.7 dosen't work  - I'm using Magento 1.8 community
Regards

Comment: It will be helpful if you place the code of your importer that did the image attachment to products. Are you using dataflow?, Magmi?, custom shell?, api? etc.

Answer (score 1):

place the below code in a file which is in root directory and execute the code.
Please take the `backup` of your database before running the code.

```
<?php 
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('thumbnail',array('neq'=>'no_selection'));

foreach($collection as $product){
    $path = "Path_of_image_here";
    if(is_file($path)){
        try {
            $product->setSmallImage($path)
            //->setThumbnail($path)
            //->setImage($path)
            ->save();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `Path_of_image_here` need to be updated to where the images are stored, like for example, `/media/import`?

Comment: correct, in your case `$path = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').DS.'import'.DS.'file_name';`

Comment: Is the filename needed? Because in the event of a 9000 product import, you're not going to update this script 9000 times for each product. Or does your suggestion above programmatically get the filename of the images in the `media/import` directory? Thanks.

Comment: to add image you will require the file name, let say import directory has all the images and the images filename are based on the SKU, for product with SKU xyz will have image filename will be xyz.jpg, create some logic similar to that. i had imported 57k product with that logic, good luck